# SimpleDateFormat issue

Tags: java, date-formatting

I have this code below and im not getting the right dates out
For example a date going in is 01/01/2013 12:35 
but the format.parse is only returning the dd/mm/yyyy and excluding the hh:mm

This is a sample date time 03/09/2012 15:26 and the output is producing 1346649960000

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
long data = format.parse(childNode.getTextContent()).getTime();
```

Any clues as to why this would be formatting the time oddly ?

Comment: what you want? The date along with time or only the date?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is giving a valid output. getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00. So last 3 zeros are for milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues in your code:

1. If you parse a 24 hours formatted time, you have to use HH instead of hh.
2. You may want to specify the time zone you are using for parsing, 15:26 in your time zone happens at a different time in another time zone.

Please see my proposed fixes below:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```